# Checking almost sure converge of a random variable experimentally

Tags: stochastic-processes, random-variables, almost-everywhere

Suppose $X_1, X_2, X_3, \ldots$ is a sequence of random variables that converges almost surely to a random variable $X$.

How could I check for this experimentally? I don't need this to be some rigorously reliable test, I would just like to do this to better understand the ideas.

For concreteness, suppose $X$ is uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$ and $X_1, X_2, \ldots$ is some process that I can simulate, and we know that $X_n \to X$ almost surely. What is nagging me is that I could produce samples $x_1^1, x_2^1, x_3^1 \ldots, $ and produce samples $x_1^2, x_2^2, x_3^3, \ldots$, etc... and then hope that, averaged over each of the limits, we "land" almost anywhere in $[0,1]$. But how do I know where to stop within each individual sequence? Isn't it possible that no individual sample sequence converges?

Comment: No, it isn’t possible that no individual sample sequence converges. They converge with probability one. This is the meaning of almost sure convergence.

Comment: Each of the sequences will converge to something in $[0,1].$ These somethings are realizations of the RV $X.$ How to generically test for convergence and decide where to stop is an orthogonal issue that strikes me as difficult in general. One would hope for “well-behaved” situations that some heuristic involving a tolerance would suffice.